# How to send data from class to activity on Android

Tags: android, class, button, android-activity, settext

I have a problem with send data from class to activity. I have class (not activity) with static method:

```
public static void printUsageStats(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList){

    long totalTime = 0;

    for (UsageStats u : usageStatsList) {
        if ((u.getTotalTimeInForeground() > 0) && u.getPackageName().equals("com.facebook.katana")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() + "\t" + "ForegroundTime: "
                    + u.getTotalTimeInForeground());

            totalTime = totalTime + u.getTotalTimeInForeground();

        }
    }
    System.out.println(totalTime);

}
```

And I need send variable *totalTime* to mainactivity to set text on textview with this variable after click button.

Here is a second method which I call in mainactivity:

```
public static void printCurrentUsageStatus(Context context){
    printUsageStats(getUsageStatsList(context));

}
```

And in onCreate mainactivity I call it:

```
statsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stats_btn);
    statsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UStats.printCurrentUsageStatus(MainActivity2.this);

        }
    });
```

But with that's way I can't set text in textview.

Comment: Where is this static method called from? From somewhere in the activity in an `onClick` method? If so, please add that to the question to show how it is called.

Comment: I just added how this method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1 - Return the value**

The most straightforward way to do that would be to just return the value you want to display from the method, like this

```java
// change return type from 'void' to 'long' and add a 'return'
public static long printUsageStats(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList){

    // your existing code...

    return totalTime;
}

public static long printCurrentUsageStatus(Context context){
    return printUsageStats(getUsageStatsList(context));
}
```

and then you can return the time value and set it within your activity

```java
textFld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text);
statsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stats_btn);

statsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long time = UStats.printCurrentUsageStatus(MainActivity2.this);
        textFld.setText(String.valueOf(time));
    }
});
```

**Method 2 - Pass the TextView as Argument**

Alternately you could pass the `TextView` into the function as an argument, then you can set the value in the static function.

```java
public static void printUsageStats(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList, TextView tv){

    // your existing code...

    tv.setText(String.valueOf(totalTime));
}

public static void printCurrentUsageStatus(Context context, TextView tv){
    printUsageStats(getUsageStatsList(context), tv);
}
```

and call it like this

```java
textFld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text);
statsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stats_btn);

statsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        UStats.printCurrentUsageStatus(MainActivity2.this, textFld);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for current implementation you can just call static method from Activity and get returned value from this method, as a easiest approach. Also you can make a DI (dagger/koin/hilt), make a repository with a LiveData and subscribe to this LiveData from Activity to get new value.